# returning array pushed value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I have an array that was populated by this script :

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imgSrcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
}
```

When I echo this out from a PHP, it gives me all the img src with commas separating them. It seems like its not like a typical array format, more like just text. When I tried to do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($img); ++$i) {
    echo "<img src='".$img."'/><br>";
}
```

It just echo's one `<img src` with every single image src that is in `imgSrcs`.

I'm trying to echo img src and 1 img link. This way if I have 5 links in `imgSrcs`, i'll output 5 images.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you passing the value of the array to php? therein lies your answer.

Comment: using ajax and into a php file $(isset($_POST['img']))

Comment: where in ajax data: "img="+imgSrcs

Comment: And I dont think that matters, because when I just do alert(imgSrcs) it outputs exactly what I'm describing: list of img sources with comma separated

Comment: With `"img="+imgSrcs` you're trying to concatenate your array onto a string, which does a `.toString()` on `imgSrcs` resulting in a comma-separated _string_ of the values from the array. Similarly, `alert()` is used to display strings, so `alert(imgSrcs)` displays your data with commas because it does a `.toString()` on your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get your array back, if you're passing it as a comma delimited list.

```
$img = explode(",",$img);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($img); ++$i) {
    echo "<img src='".$img."'/><br>";
}
```

Comment: This turned it into Arrays, but it gave me a good start. Thanks